# Killing a process spawned by another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a Python process which is spawning another process from a separate thread, e.g.

```
class MyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        def spawn_proc():
            subprocess.call("test_process")

        thread = threading.Thread(target=spawn_proc, args=(), daemon=True)
        thread.start()

    def cleanup(self):
        # @@@ kill test_process
```

So calling `MyClass.setup()` means the `test_process` will be spawned in second thread.

What I want is a way to kill `test_process` from this first thread. I've tried saving a reference to the process in `spawn_proc()`, but this is inaccessible in the first as `spawn_proc()` is executed in the second thread.

What is the best way to do this? Or is this approach incorrect from the off?

What *does* work is another call to `subprocess` to lookup the PID from the OS, then a further call to kill, but I'm not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: interesting question. I have never tried, but I would think it's possible to act on a resource from different threads. Why don't you save the reference to the process in the object instance (e.g. `self. sub_process_id = ...`), if you have one, of course?

Comment: @Pynchia I'm using the unittest framework, and the class above inherits from unittest.TestCase (sorry I haven't added this in the question yet!). This means the methods are all called under separate instances of this class, so saving attributes does not work :-(

Comment: ah, alright. Are you saying you want to start a thread and process in one test and kill them later in another?

Comment: @Pynchia exactly, yes. setup() spawns a thread which spawns a process, cleanup() needs to kill that same process.

Comment: I have used unittest and I had no problem adding attributes to `self`.  You add them in `setup` and they are visible afterwards in your `test*` and `cleanup`.

Comment: exactly, they are called before and after the same test. My prev question asked wheter you intended to keep a thread/process alive between two or more different tests.

Comment: @ExP Even if I could, I think this still wouldn't work; the function that tried to save the subprocess reference is going to be run in another thread.

Comment: threads share data segment/memory space. Processes don't

Comment: @Pynchia yes, the process is supposed to stay alive until cleanup() is called after all the tests have run. The thread itself doesn't matter; once it's spawned the process, it's served its purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `subprocess.call()` doesn't return any thread handle.  It's a synchronous method (it returns only when the called program terminated).

Instead use `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
def setup(self):
    self.proc = subprocess.Popen("test_process")


def cleanup(self):
    self.proc.kill()
```

Not only do you get a handle, you also avoid the `threading` module altogether.

More details on `Popen` (e.g. how to communicate with the process):
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: This is great, thank you. I was being silly and assuming that because self.proc wasn't being set, it was a threading issue; in reality it's because subprocess.call() did not return :-)